# what is the actual and exact meaning of memory mapped terms used in context of register-interfaces in fpga design?

Tags: memory, fpga, cpu-registers, register-transfer-level

So many times, I have heard these terms in the `FPGA` design process, and to my knowledge, which I gather from a Google search, it's like some data is going to be transmitted from the core to memory.

Let's say a system where the 1st block is Zynq ps (cortex A-9 processor core) and the 2nd block is AXI GPIO, which is connected through some intermediate interfaces (AXI interconnect), so processors treat `axi gpio` as memory. This is what I know through some sources, but I want to actually feel it and digest it so, I need proper explanation.

When we get to know that it is memory-mapped in the context of registers, and interfaces. In general, a register is always memory, so we say it's memory-mapped Register and in the context of processor a how do we know that it is a memory-mapped interface?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A memory mapped interface is one that can be **accessed** by the CPU as if it was memory. In particular the same instructions (and often also address space) can be used to access the peripheral.

Memory would behave such that a value written to a certain address could be read back again from there unchanged.
However, a memory mapped peripheral is not necessarily **behaving** as memory. Instead it can have behaviors such as

- write only addresses, for instance to issue a command when a certain bit is set. The value read back might always be 0.
- read only addresses, to feed data to the CPU. For instance status registers. They could have a different value every time they are read
- side effects on read or write. For instance a message could be transmitted everytime a register is written
- of course it can also contain just plain memory behind certain registers. For instance for a message buffer.

A main **advantage** is that the CPU and Software do not need special instructions to access it, they might not even meet to "know".

A **drawback** can be that the CPU or Software not knowing about it, might introcude errors. For instance a compiler could optimize out a write access to a memory mapped register, assuming it was never read. Or speculative caching might trigger side effects in the peripheral if the MMU is not correctly configured.